# React material-ui (MUI) 5 conditional CSS classes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm moving from React material-ui 4 to MUI 5.

How do I achieve this type of pattern using the new `styled` API (or whatever makes sense)?

I'm using Typescript.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    topBar: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: TRANSITION_DURATION,
        }),
        marginLeft: DRAWER_WIDTH,
    },
    topBarShift: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: TRANSITION_DURATION,
        }),
        marginLeft: 0,
    },
}));

function Header({ drawer }: IHeader) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    ...

    return (
        <div className={`${classes.topBar} ${!drawer && classes.topBarShift}`}>
           ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, you just want a conditional `string`.

This can be done by creating a `util` function for reusability:

```js
type ConditionalClasses = {
  [className: string]: bool
}

const conditionalClass = (classes: ConditionalClass) => 
  Object.keys(classes).reduce((combinedClassName, className) => classes[className] ? `${combinedClassName} ${className}` : combinedClassName, "")
```

Usage goes as follows

```js
// Output: "a"
const newClassName = conditionalClasses({a: true, b: false})
```

Alternatively, you could use [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)

-- Edit

Looks like I misread and hence misunderstood the question.

If you want to use the `styled` API `styles` conditionally, you can use the `overridesResolver` option provided by the `styled` API.

```js
const CustomDivComponent = styled("div", {
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => {
    // Do your conditional logic here.
    // Return the new style.
    return {};
  }
})(({ theme }) => ({
  // Your original styles here...
}));
```

More documentation can be found [here](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api)

Comment: With material-ui 5 makeStyles() has been replaced with styled(). Was looking for the new equivalent.

Comment: @TyKroll I looked at the [documentation](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#:~:text=from%20%27%40mui/styles%27%3B-,makeStyles,-The) `makeStyles` hasn't been replaced (or deprecated for that matter). If you're talking about using moving away from `jss`, as described [here](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#1-use-styled-or-sx-api), let me know and I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: @TyKroll new answer should be what you're looking for, let me know though :)

Comment: @TyKroll did this answer your question? If so, please mark it as approved :) If not, please let me know there's any clarification to be made.

Comment: I decided to totally rewrite from scratch so didn't need the above approach. It is indeed the correct answer regardless. Thanks.